# The code is jumping to an uncalled function

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code where I can fill different amounts ir order. I can create more inputs in order to create more amounts to calculate them. But for some reason, when I press enter in one of them in order to create another input/entry, it goes to the Reset function, which erases every field. It shouldn't call the reset function on the key press.

```
var intId = 0;
var maindiv = $("#maindiv");
var divpeso ="";
var inputnumber ="";
var fieldname = "";
var removeButton = "";


function anadir_input() {
    // var lastField = $("#container div:last");
    intId = intId + 1;
    divpeso = $("<div class=\"input-group mb-3\" id=\"divpeso" + intId + "\"/>");

    inputnumber = $("<input id=\"peso" + intId + "\" type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"peso" + intId + "\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" step=\".01\" />");
    fieldname = $("<div class=\"input-group-append\"><span class=\"input-group-text\">Peso" + intId + "</span></div>");
    removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-danger\" value=\"Quitar\" />");

    removeButton.click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    inputnumber.keypress(function (e) {
           if (e.which == 13) {
           console.log("enter apretado");
        }
    });

    divpeso.append(inputnumber);
    divpeso.append(fieldname);
    divpeso.append(removeButton);
    $("#container").append(divpeso);
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#anadir").click(function () {
        anadir_input();
    });

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        console.log("reset");
        $('[id*=divresultado]:visible').each(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('[id^=peso]:visible').each(function () {
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $('[id^=divpeso]:visible').each(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        intId = 0;
    });


    $("#resultado").click(function () {
        var pesosordenados = [];
        var capacidad = Number($("#capacidad").val());
        var pesos = [];
        capacidad = $("#capacidad").val();
        $('[id*=divresultado]:visible').each(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('[id^=peso]:visible').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != 0 || $(this).val() != null || $(this).val() != undefined)
                pesos.push($(this).val());
            pesosordenados = pesos.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b - a
            });
        });

        var contenedores = [];
        var sobrepesos = [];

        //algoritmo para rellenar los contenedores con los distintos pesos.
        while (pesosordenados.length > 0) {
            var unidadcontenedor = [];
            var pesosnousados = [];
            var restcapacidad = Number(capacidad);
            for (var i = 0; i < pesosordenados.length; i++) {
                if (Number(pesosordenados[i]) > capacidad) { //si el peso es mas grande que la capacidad del contenedor
                    sobrepesos.push(Number(pesosordenados[i]));
                } else {
                    if (Number(pesosordenados[i]) <= restcapacidad && restcapacidad >= pesosordenados[pesosordenados.length - 1]) {
                        unidadcontenedor.push(Number(pesosordenados[i]));
                        restcapacidad = restcapacidad - Number(pesosordenados[i]);
                    } else {
                        pesosnousados.push(pesosordenados[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
            contenedores.push(unidadcontenedor);
            pesosordenados = pesosnousados;
        }


        for (var m = 0; m < contenedores.length; m++) {
            var divresultado = $("<div id=\"divresultado\" class=\"calculadora\"></div>");
            var titulo = $("<h5 class=\"card-title\">Contenedor " + (Number(m) + 1) + "</h5>");
            var contpesorelleno = $("<h5 class=\"card-title\">Peso cargado: " + contenedores[m].reduce((a, n) => (a + Number(n)), 0) + "</h5>");
            var contpesolibre = $("<h5 class=\"card-title\">Peso libre: " + (Number(capacidad) - Number(contenedores[m].reduce((a, n) => (a + Number(n)), 0))) + "</h5>");

            divresultado.append(titulo);
            divresultado.append(contpesorelleno);
            divresultado.append(contpesolibre);
            for (var n = 0; n < contenedores[m].length; n++) {
                var resultfield = $("<div class=\"input-group-append\"><span class=\"input-group-text\">" + contenedores[m][n] + "</span></div>");
                divresultado.append(resultfield);
            }
            maindiv.append(divresultado);
        }


//para sumar toda una array: arrayloquesea.reduce((a, n) => (a + Number(n)), 0)


    });


});
```

You have the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L0oa3bed/).

Steps to reproduce:

-Press the green button "Añadir peso".

-Click on the created input field and press enter.

Another input field is created but also reset function erases them all.

**EDIT:**

I solved the issue with *type="reset"* in the html and also with *e.preventDefault();* in the keypress function in the js. However, it does not show the div `maindiv.append(divresultado);` with the results.

Comment: are you adding another object that has the same id of an existing one?

Comment: `reset` is not called.  If you remove the reset handler you get the same behavior.  Your logic is wiping our your data array somewhere else.

Comment: @StevenSpungin when I use F12 on the browser and I use stop points (sorry I don't know in English how are they called) I can see that it jumps inside the reset function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine just type="reset" is missing in reset button.

```
  <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-danger cincuw">Reset</button>
```

Comment: I did this, and now when I press enter the code creates another input and then executes $("#resultado").click(function ()... It should execute this part as I'm not clicking "Resultado" button.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not reseting, you are not providing the input value to begin with, your js `$("#anadir").click()` function should look like this:

```
$("#anadir").click(function () {
     anadir_input($('input[name="capacidad"]').val());
});
```

and `anadir_input` function should put the passed input value:

```
function anadir_input(inputValue) {
    // var lastField = $("#container div:last");
    intId = intId + 1;
    divpeso = $("<div class=\"input-group mb-3\" id=\"divpeso" + intId + "\"/>");

    inputnumber = $("<input id=\"peso" + intId + "\" type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"peso" + intId + "\" maxlength=\"5\" size=\"5\" step=\".01\" value='"+inputValue+"' />");
    fieldname = $("<div class=\"input-group-append\"><span class=\"input-group-text\">Peso" + intId + "</span></div>");
    removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-outline-danger\" value=\"Quitar\" />");

    removeButton.click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    inputnumber.keypress(function (e) {
           if (e.which == 13) {
           console.log("enter apretado");
        }
    });

    divpeso.append(inputnumber);
    divpeso.append(fieldname);
    divpeso.append(removeButton);
    $("#container").append(divpeso);
};
```

I have changed your fiddle to see the output  difference: https://jsfiddle.net/z4sgnr28/

*I hope it makes sense*

Comment: The input that were empty is because numbers will be introduced manually. Is not that I need to get the value on the top. Let me explain better: The top input value (24300) is the max capacity of a container. The inputs created above are weights, that must be typed by hand. 
In the fiddle you shared, the problem is still there, if I press enter on one of the created inputs, everything gets deleted.

Comment: Can't edit, but I meant "the inputs created below are weights".

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, use 'type="button"' for the buttons which are not supposed to submit the form and use the form submit property to show the result. See the updated fiddle, now its showing some other error which you might be able to resolve as its your code.

Comment: @Germán Any luck here? have you checked the latest changes I did in your fiddle?

Comment: I erased all the submits and put a name in each "type". Now it is working fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Germán glad it worked, please define an answer for your own question and accept that or just accept one of the answers which helped you the most in order to reach to the concluded solution so that we may mark this thread as completed on stackoverflow. Thank you!